# Weird spiky shadows around the edges of my walls

Tags: edges, lighting, shadows, reflection, ambient-occlusion

I am new to blender and was trying to model an interior of a room. I used an Irradiance volume around the entire house and an environmental lighting. In the render properties, I have enabled ambient occlusion and screen space reflections with default settings. After baking the indirect lighting, I am getting these spiky shadows around the edges of the walls.
[image]

Comment: It is quite hard to see what we are looking at (in this kind of detail). It looks like a forest on horizon in a fogy weather behinde a glass :) OK Would be better to post simplified blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com Do you have a lights in corners or is it penetrated from outside?

Comment: yes there are area lights on the edges of the ceiling. And yes behind the window i have an environmental lighting.

Comment: I cant reproduce the issue, please share your simplified file as suggested in my comment. Try remove all objects that doesn't contribute on the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like that generates *Sun* light.

[image]

You can try to get rid of by *Shadow - Cascade Shadow Map -* **Max Distance**, but seems to be a tricky solution.

[image]

This effect is such visible when Lamp light is switched to Sun where Strenght of light is too high (1000). Lower value to 3 is ussually fine in most cases.

[image]

---

**Edit**
Later I noticed - light still penetrates the corners

[image]

Enable **Contact Shadow** subpanel and play a bit with values

[image]

... or, instead all of this, use another type of light :)

Comment: How do you fix it?

Comment: @marcellothearcane answer edited